# Odoo install app ,Error:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Odoo Server Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 648, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 685, in dispatch
．．．．．．．．．．．．．．．
    return api.model(lambda model: field.convert_to_write(value(model)))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/fields.py", line 1719, in convert_to_write
    return value.id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I get this error everytime I install the system app. Why am I encountering it and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Please as some more details so, we can help.

Comment: Ｉ　remove a purchase's App．Ａfter that,When I installed the system APP, this error occurred，this error info,

Comment: what do you mean by system app?

Comment: some of the installed module may depend on purchase module,